# ClickOnce Update - Change Update URL or Assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

We have a ClickOnce deployed C# application which is installed on several thousand computers. This application has two branches - one live and one beta/testing. Both have different update URLs and different assembly names (XXX-live and XXX-beta). We now want to consolidate all installations to use the live branch in order to publish the next big update. Is it possible to switch the beta apps to the live somehow without reinstalling the app from the live branch - possibly through changing the update URL with the next release?

Answer (score 0):

You can by creating a 'loader' application.

**Step 1**
Download the assembly bytes from the website

**Step 2**
Create an assembly instance object

**Step 3**
Show the assembly by invoking the `.ctor`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> without reinstalling the app from the live branch

As ClickOnce is downloaded to the client PC, you will need to "reinstall from the live branch" to replace the local copy of the beta.

The `t` and `fd` command line options for mage.exe allows you to specify where the target application (version) manifest file and deployment files are - so you should be able to simply regenerate the main product manifest for the published beta product by running mage from the command line. Note that you'll also need to supply a path to your signing certificate and you'll need to know its password.